# Adding peer nodes to existing fabric

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

If I have an existing fabric installation with transactions on the blockchain, can I just add another empty peer node, and will it get caught up with the ledger?

Answer (score 1):

Run peer node with `CORE_PEER_DISCOVERY_ROOTNODE` variable.

Comment: Yes - I'm doing that.  I'm asking operationally, what should we expect to happen if I add a new peer node?